# What card or board game was first played in space?

Tags: astronaut-lifestyle, spaceflight-firsts

Was it chess, blackjack or some other game that was first played in space?

Answer (score 11):

“Cosmonaut Andriyan Nikolayev (1929-2004), along with cosmonaut Vitaly Sevastianov, played chess against the ground crew during their Soyuz 9 spaceflight on June 9, 1970.”

From a [chessmaniac page on chess in space](http://www.chessmaniac.com/astronauts-cosmonauts-and-chess/), which has much more info.

Comment: Was there potentially anything before in the first 20 or so spaceflights?

Comment: "Velcro chessboard". Now, I'm trying to imagine all board game and card game I know with Velcro on it.

Comment: fyi I've just asked [What electronic game was first played in space?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/53840/12102)