# Indoor games played by Astronauts in Manned spacecrafts

Tags: crewed-spaceflight, astronaut-lifestyle, reduced-gravity-sports

What are the possible indoor games can be played by Astronauts on Spacecrafts as part of recreation?

Playing cards, Chess, Table tennis, Scrabble etc.

Since no gravity in space, there could be limited indoor games or no games at all which can be played?

Comment: different but related: [What electronic game was first to be played in space?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/53840/12102) and [What card or board game was first played in space?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/33544/12102) and [Do astronauts play reduced gravity sports when folks on Earth aren't watching? Ever quasi-regularly?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/54591/12102)

Comment: This is too broad, and is asking for a list.

Comment: Magnet or clips can be used for board and card games to replace gravity so those are easily adaptable, but anything requiring a *bouncing trajectory* (e.g. basketball, [Hackey sack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hacky_sack)) or a large field are obviously out. It's also really hard to make things roll smoothly in a straight line on flat surfaces *since magnets are at least dipoles*. It's a col question but I agree it may be necessary to constrain it somehow, the number of "possible indoor games" is just too big for a Stack Exchange answer.